# What is the relationship here, One to Many or a Many to Many?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I am building a project(using django) whereby agents are issued with phones. When a phone gets damaged the agent sends the phone to hq for repairs. In the meantime, the agent is issued with another different phone. Once the phone gets repaired, its then issued to another agent who may have similar problems as the first agent.
What is the relationship between the phone and agent keep in mind i want to preserve the history of phone ownership and also avoid having data that says " `Phone` x with `imei` XXXXX and Phone.Status=active is currently being used by more than one agent"

I am still in planning phase but i cant crack this one

Answer (score 5):

As for the relation, it is a many-to-one relation, since at any given point in time, the `Phone` is assigned to at most one agent.

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    pass


class Phone(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # …
```

in order to track these in time, you can work with [**`django-simple-history`** <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) this will for each model it tracks in time, make a "shadow model", that contains the records through time. It will thus make a variant of `Phone` to assign to `agent1`, and then later to `agent2`.

Comment: @ willeM_Van Onsem are these "shadow model" deltas? or  snapshots?

Comment: @Frustrated_coder: snapshots.

Comment: thanks also why would the relationship be ManyToOne and not a OneToOne given that an Agent can have at most one phone at any given time?

Comment: @Frustrated_coder: a `ForeignKey` is always a many-to-one: all phones refer to *one* agent, but multiple `Phone`s all can refer to the *same* `Agent`.